# SSRS report does not parse multiple xml elements

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am looking to display data on two tablixes from a single dataset created from an xml. Following is a sample xml. I have created two tablixes with filter on SchemeCategoryType (i.e. Stakeholder or Non-Stakeholder). So one tablix will display information from a particular SchemeCategoryType. I have then created row groups to get data for a specific MemberContributionType (Non-Contracted Out in this example). Then I am trying to display Contribution amount for ContributionType "Individual" under this RowGroup. The trouble I am facing here is that the tablix only parses the first  node so in this case I get a blank display. Any advice on what am I doing wrong here?

To add I am using one Dataset i.e. "SchemeMembers".

```xml
<SchemeMembers SchemeCategoryType="Stakeholder" SchemeSponsorType="Non-Employer" MemberContributionType="Non-Contracted Out" NumberOfMembers="41">
  <SchemeContributions ContributionType="" ContributionAmount="85000.00">
  </SchemeContributions>
  <SchemeContributions ContributionType="Individual" ContributionAmount="123824.56">
  </SchemeContributions>
  <SchemeContributions ContributionType="Employer" ContributionAmount="9118.93">
  </SchemeContributions>
</SchemeMembers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DataSet could query all values from the xml, and then add a Filter:

Query Example:

```
<Query>
<ElementPath>*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

DataSet Filter:

[image]